# How come a question got closed by 3 votes rather than 5?

Tags: discussion, closing

This question: [Infinite-dimensional translation-invariant measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167466/infinite-dimensional-translation-invariant-measure) is closed with the message:

> closed as exact duplicate by t.b., cardinal, Willie Wong♦ 1 hour ago

That's 3 votes, but the [FAQ says](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#close):

> When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked as closed

Does moderator's votes (Willie's, in this case) count as 3 votes?!

Comment: If there have been $k$ votes, then the moderator's vote counts for $5-k$.  I.e., moderator votes are always final.  Similarly, a moderator's vote to open, delete, or undelete are final.  If a moderator flags a comment as offensive it is automatically deleted.  I don't have a reference handy.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of, or at least answered by this previous question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/number-of-votes-needed-to-close-a-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderator's votes are always binding.  A reason why is provided as answer to [this question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/number-of-votes-needed-to-close-a-question)

See also:  [List of all moderator privileges.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role/75192#75192)